# Email sent by me to my group not reaching inbox

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I have the following situation. I have a collaborative inbox group: `info@`, and I have an email alias `contact@`.

I'm using `contact@` on my website contact form - in other words, the contact form is set up to send an email as `contact@`. The email needs to be sent to `info@`.

This creates a problem, because the email never reaches my inbox. According to this Google help article [Messages sent to email alias or Group aren't in my inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1703601?hl=en), it's a feature - to prevent clutter, when you send an email to your alias or a group you belong to, it skips the inbox. The resolution there doesn't seem to help (or maybe I misunderstood what they want).

How do make it such that I could still receive this email in my inbox unread? (I'm a Google Workspace admin)

<sup>(the only other solution that could work is to create another Google Workspace account to send the contact email from, but I'd like to avoid that additional cost)</sup>

**Additional info per comments:**

I tried the [Google-suggested approach (Step 1: Add an address you own)](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F1703601%3Fhl%3Den&product_context=1703601&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a) in the following way:

1. I removed all the existing email aliases that I had, which included `contact@`
2. I re-added `contact@` "as alias" -> same effect.
3. I changed `contact@` to uncheck "as alias" -> same effect.

Comment: Did you try the resolution specified on the page you linked (Set up the alias or Group as an alternate "Send mail as" address for your account.)?https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?visit_id=637962911191260152-44241492&rd=1

Comment: @BlindSpots, I tried what I thought I understood from that page. I tried with marking the other emails "as alias" and not, but it still didn't work

Comment: Based on your wording you may not be 100% sure.  Can you again try Google's proposed solution & confirm definitively (with surety) that you have completed it and the outcome (1. same, 2. not same but still not solved, 3. resolved).  If there's a point in the steps where doesn't match what you can do, or there's another issue that makes you question if you've done what was asked or what they're asking doesn't make sense/apply, note where that happened in the steps,  & what the issue was.  I'd like to eliminate their solution as the resolution to your problem.  Happy to continue helping.

Comment: @BlindSpots - I edited the question, but in a nutshell, adding a new email address didn't seem to help.

Comment: My read of the support article https://support.google.com/a/answer/1703601?hl=en seems to be that the info@ alias/group needs the "send as" privileges, not the contact@ alias.  It does seem counterintuitive and the article could be better written, however can you test that out as well to see if it makes a difference.